# Read uint8 array with json style in matlab

Tags: json, matlab, ros

I read a json `uint8[] data` array from rostopic and it gave the wield output

The topic I want to echo is `/head_camera/depth/points`

The data type of it is `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.msg`
which has the following elements:

```
std_msgs/Header header  uint32 height 
uint32 width 
sensor_msgs/PointField[] fields 
bool is_bigendian 
uint32 point_step 
uint32 row_step 
uint8[] data 
bool is_dense
```

I send the json message below to receive data:

```
{
  "op":"subscribe",
  "topic":"/head_camera/depth/points"
}
```

And I recieve the message like (use fscanf() in matlab):

```
{"topic": "/head_camera/depth/points", "msg": {"width": 640, "is_dense": false, "point_step": 16, "height": 480, "header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1453928112, "nsecs": 53613655}, "frame_id": "head_camera_rgb_optical_frame", "seq": 0}, "data": "AADAfwAAwH8AAMB/AAAAAAAAwH8AAMB/AADAfwAAAAAAAM
```

Just the "data" part is incorrect, so how to deal with that?

Comment: Could you be more specific please? Giving your code, the original Json and the end result?

Comment: I reedit the question, you can see the detail